# Confusion on apt-cache policy: same origin but different versions?

Tags: apt, package-management, php

**Background:**

I have a Debian container  that installs `libapache2-mod-php` and is running PHP `7.2` server. It has been set up half a year ago and is running fine.

---

**Problem:**

This week I've been trying to install the Debian containers on another VM with the same OS.

It seems like this package has gotten an update recently (defaults to `7.3`) which breaks my PHP `7.2` server after the installation.

---

**Attempts:**

I've tried `apt policy libapache2-mod-php`, it shows both environments contains the same origins, but both `libapache2-mod-php`s' versions of the same origin are different.

I am really confused as in how to specify apt to install PHP `7.2` when there's no available version on `apt policy`?

---

**Broken Container:**

```
root@b3ec62f3096d:/srv/server/server# apt policy libapache2-mod-php
libapache2-mod-php:
  Installed: 2:7.3+69+0~20190303094804.15+stretch~1.gbp0f7465
  Candidate: 2:7.3+69+0~20190303094804.15+stretch~1.gbp0f7465
  Version table:
 *** 2:7.3+69+0~20190303094804.15+stretch~1.gbp0f7465 500
        500 https://packages.sury.org/php stretch/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:7.0+49 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
```

**Working Container:**

```
root@430822ee576a:/srv/server/server# apt policy libapache2-mod-php
libapache2-mod-php:
  Installed: 1:7.2+65+0~20181014094036.7+stretch~1.gbpaaf4ee
  Candidate: 1:7.2+65+0~20181014094036.7+stretch~1.gbpaaf4ee
  Version table:
 *** 1:7.2+65+0~20181014094036.7+stretch~1.gbpaaf4ee 500
        500 https://packages.sury.org/php stretch/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:7.0+49 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The broken container is really your “working container”, in a dead-man-walking fashion: its repository caches are outdated, so `apt policy` is telling you something which was true in the past but no longer is. If you run `apt update` in it, you’ll see the same situation as in your “broken container”.

If you really need PHP 7.2, you need to install the corresponding package instead of the `libapache2-mod-php` package, which will always pull in the latest stable PHP version. Installing `libapache2-mod-php7.2` should fix your issue.